# Smaller JSON Format

Tags: json, serialization, deserialization

I'm going to develop a pushing server (HTML5 WebSocket/Polling) and in order to reduce the size of packets (that presents in JSON format) I want to do something like this with packets:

```
[["id", "username", "password"], [1, "afshin", "123"], [2, "barak", "meme"]]
```

Instead of clear JSON format like:

```
[{"id": 1, "username": "afshin", "password": "123"}, {"id": 2, "username": "barak", "password": "meme"}]
```

Exactly, I want to prevent sending contract properties in each object.

So, I want to know is there any library for doing this (or something like)? I have C# on server and JavaScript on clients.

Comment: Why don't you simply use CSV in response? Something like `1, afshin, 123; 2, barak, meme;`

Comment: If your concern is minimizing network payload, be sure to use HTTP compression. If you are using Apache httpd, look at mod_deflate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON DB](http://michaux.ca/articles/json-db-a-compressed-json-format) or [RJSON](http://www.cliws.com/e/06pogA9VwXylo_GknPEeFA/) should be exactly what you're looking for. You'll most likely have to implement serializers/deserializers yourself (RJSON is already implemented in JS though).

As for compressing pure JSON, I think you could bypass the "keys are needed" rule by wrapping all your data in a single object entry:

```
{"data" : [["id", "username", "password"], [1, "afshin", "123"], [2, "barak", "meme"]]}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, besides all the arguments against manual compression, this would be a solution:

```
var input = [{"id": 1, "username": "afshin", "password": "123"}, {"id": 2, "username": "barak", "password": "meme"}];


var keys = {}

input.map ( function (e) { Object.keys(e).map( function (k) { keys[k] = 1; })});

var output = [ Object.keys(keys) ] .concat( input.map( function (e) {
    return Object.keys(keys).map( function (k) { return e[k]; } );
} ) );

console.log(output);
```

and Node.js produces:

```
[ [ 'id', 'username', 'password' ],
  [ 1, 'afshin', '123' ],
  [ 2, 'barak', 'meme' ] ]
```

I really don't know if this works with every browser etc.

Answer (score 0):

By removing the name of the name-value pair you'd be breaking a JSON syntax rule. Effectively, it wouldn't be JSON. You also might cause problems for JSON client deserialization. Could you consider reducing the length of your names:

```
[{"id": 1, "u": "afshin", "p": "123"}, {"id": 2, "u": "barak", "p": "meme"}]
```

This JSON document is the same size as the one you propose above.